# Drag text over C# application icon to launch app

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I have a C#, Windows 7, forms application that works with the clipboard to retrieve text and then process it accordingly.  I'd like to modify the app to allow a user to highlight text from any source (word, e-mail, etc.) and drag that text over my applications icon to launch the program.

I can get command line arguments to work like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    if (args != null)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++){
         varItemNumber = args[i];
      }
    }//...
```

But the application wont launch on the desktop when text is dropped on it.

Found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214150/drag-and-drop-text-to-c-sharp-console-application-exe) which is related to console applications.

Is there a way to enable objects to be dropped onto the application icon?

Comment: Well, this is just an idea, not a solution, but if you had some kind of stub already running, you might be able to hook into the OS and monitor drags and drops within Windows.  Then you could detect when one was happening above your application's icon.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854966/drag-and-drop-onto-desktop-icon?rq=1), what you're doing ought to work.  SOme people recommend this attribute over the `Main` function:

```
 [STAThread]
```

But other people have complained that UAC issues have prevented them doing this.  So that (UAC) might be part of the issue.

Another thought:  might you get different results for a shortcut vs. actually having the application installed to the desktop?

Finally:  according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571011/drag-and-drop-from-outlook-window-to-application-exe-file-or-icon-in-net?rq=1), what you need is a Shell Drop Handler.

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that post as well but it doesn't help as the application isn't launching on the drop event.  So it never get's to that line of code.

Comment: I've tried both with & without `[STAThread]` as well as your idea of using a shortcut... no luck.  Good ideas

Comment: I've added a final suggestion:  a shell drop handler - which may or may not be implementable in C#. :(